# Looking for the fastest way to divide dictionary keys (based on values) into lists of list such that each list does not cross a certain threshold

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, data-structures, sliding-window

I have an OrderedDictionary
`a =  {"1":800, "2":400, "3":600, "4":200, "5":100, "6":400}`

I would like to divide the keys into a list of lists such that each list's total values do not exceed a threshold value (600 in this case) or if a value is greater than the threshold value it should have its own list. Also, we only check for the next key (like a sliding window).

The above dictionary should return `expected = [['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4', '5'], ['6']]`. For example, `'1'` has its own list since it is greater than threshold. `'2'` has its own list since values of `'2' + '3'` is greater than threshold. `['4', '5']` has values totalling up to `600` and if we append `'6'`, it exceeds the threshold.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def check_result(a):
    
    result = {}
    curr_val = 0 
    threshold = 600
    l =[]
    result = []

    for i in a.keys():
        if curr_val >= threshold:
           result.append(l)
           l = []
           curr_val = 0

        if curr_val + a[i] > threshold:
          result.append(l)
          l = [i]
          curr_val = a[i]
        else:
          l.append(i)
          curr_val += a[i]

    

   result.append(l)
   print(result)
```

It gives the output as `[[], ['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4', '5'], ['6']]`.

Looking for a correct solution in O(n) time.

Thanks!

Comment: updated it, it was supposed to be `l`

Comment: Why do you think that your solution is not O(n)?

Comment: The sublist have to be contiguous?

Comment: Yes @DaniMesejo

Comment: @mkrieger my solution right now is in O(n) but I don't think it is 100% correct, also I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way

Answer (score 0):

The second `if` should just have an extra check that `l` is not empty:

```
if curr_val + a[i] > threshold and l:
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly less cumbersome code:-

```
a = {"1": 800, "2": 400, "3": 600, "4": 200, "5": 100, "6": 400}


def check_result(d):
    T = 600
    result, e = [], []
    s = 0
    for k, v in d.items():
        if e:
            if s + v > T:
                result.append(e)
            else:
                e.append(k)
                s += v
                continue
        e = [k]
        s = v
    if e:
        result.append(e)
    return result


print(check_result(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the running sum, you can streamline the code by toggling the list to append keys to between the whole result and its last sublist.

```
a =  {"1":800, "2":400, "3":600, "4":200, "5":100, "6":400}
t = 600  # Treshold

r = []   # result, list of lists of keys
s = 0    # running sum
for k,v in a.items():
    group,item,delta = (r[-1],k,v) if r and s+v<=t else (r,[k],v-s)
    group.append(item)  # append to result or last sublist
    s += delta          # update running sum

print(r)
[['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4', '5'], ['6']]
```

Or this somewhat shorter (but less efficient) variant:

```
r,s = [],0   # result, running sum
for k,v in a.items():
    r += [r.pop(-1)+[k] if r and s+v<=t else [k]]
    s += v - s*(s+v>t)
```